# Columns in where all the values are identical Error

Tags: r, variables, hierarchical-clustering

In the R Package - ClustOfVar, there are methods to cluster Variables with Each other. It gives the error as below -

```
train2 = train[!duplicated(lapply(train, summary))]
> tree <- hclustvar(train2[, 2:10])
Error in recodquant(X.quanti) : 
  There are columns in X.quanti where all the values are identical
```

From what I understand, to ensure that my Variables are not identical, i have  applied the duplicated logic to remove duplicate variables.

I checked the  package code on https://github.com/cran/PCAmixdata/blob/master/R/recodquant.R but could not identify the mistake.

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is not correct to correctly identify duplicates -

```
train2 = train[!duplicated(lapply(train, summary))]
```

Pls use the below -

```
library(digest)
train2 = train[!duplicated(lapply(train, digest))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is not the problem of identical columns. I tried the above solutions, that did not work for me.
While reading about the ClustOfVar package, I got to know, it internally calculates the correlation between the variables. Then, I calculate the cross correlation between the variables. and `I find that the cross correlation between some variables was NA`. Then, I remove those variables manually and i work for me.

Use `xcor = cor(data)` to calculate the cross correlation between the variables.
Export the cross correlation data using
`write.csv(xcor, 'xcor.csv')`

`Check for the variable for which correlation is NA`, and remove these variables and again run the code.

reference: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v050i13/v50i13.pdf

The reference above explains how ClustOfVar works.